# Should Stack Exchange be using the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, security

I was just reading a [blog article](https://www.barracuda.com/blogs/labsblog?bid=1743) about the security of Google+, and the page mentioned a header I hadn't heard of before: `X-Frame-Options`

I'll let the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) do most of the talking, but suffice it to say this header allows you to say whether or not a page is allowed to be used as part of a frame (there are options to deny the ability outright, or restrict it to pages from the same domain). See also [the informational Internet-Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-x-frame-options-01).

Given that frame busting has been [a feature of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed) for as long as I can remember, doesn't it make sense to include this header as an added layer of protection for those using a somewhat recent browser?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt, I'd say. Nice security feature.

Comment: Related (also mentions this header): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70637/allow-users-to-decline-running-the-framebusting-script-when-prompted/70655#70655.

Comment: @balpha I did see that before I posted this here. Since it hasn't been implemented, I suppose it was sort of an implicit [status-declined] but I figured it wouldn't hurt to bring it up again as a fallback option of sorts. Especially since that answer is close to a year old at this point.

Comment: A nicely illustrated example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/01/27/ie8-security-part-vii-clickjacking-defenses.aspx).

Comment: This is a nice idea but as with most things on the Internet, it gets broken pretty quickly by proxies that strip it out.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison At that point, you're really just saying that SO should just go full-HTTPS and encrypt the whole shebang. If you're using an evil proxy, you've already lost anyway. Should SO also stop sending their frame-busting JS in case a proxy swallows the request? This is just a "so long as we're already trying to stop framing, let's go all the way and send an extra 30-40 characters and let the browsers do some of the work" sort of suggestion. It's a supplement to the JS, not a replacement. It's a bit of extra security with negligible cost.

Comment: [Listen](http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/01/27/us-facebook-spam-lawsuits-idUSTRE80Q07120120127) and [learn](http://javascript.info/tutorial/clickjacking).

Comment: This has been implemented at some point.

Comment: @lunboks Just noticed this myself and came to check this out because I didn't remember this post ever being updated. Flagging for retagging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has finally been added:

[image: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN]

and

[image: Refused to display 'stackoverflow.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN']