# Stack Overflow vulnerable to clickjacking

Tags: bug, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should StackOverflow be using the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103405/should-stackoverflow-be-using-the-x-frame-options-header)

Stack Overflow and all of the Stack Exchange sites are vulnerable to [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking).

You need to set the [x-frame-options](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking#X-FRAME-OPTIONS) header to prevent an attacker from creating new posts,  voting, and editing the user page,  or probably just set it site wide.

On a side note you should probably have someone on your team actively reviewing security because this is the 3rd obvious vulnerability I have reported.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks  so wait,  you mean to tell me this is a known issue that no one has fixed?  WTF!?

Comment: Agonizing as it is, having entirely perfect security hasn't been a priority for the developers.

Comment: A nicely illustrated example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/01/27/ie8-security-part-vii-clickjacking-defenses.aspx).