# Add 'Works best with JavaScript enabled' to http://stackexchange.com/users/[userID]?tab=reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, status-declined, network-profile, noscript

This is the page if JavaScript is disabled:

[image: no image or message displayed]

A table or the "works best with JavaScript enabled" would be sufficient.

Comment: There ought to be a big red bar on the top of the page saying "JS is not enabled _blah blah_"

Comment: ... like there is on the rest of the network.

Comment: Ah, [indeed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4yp4A.png), like @Pekka says. Just not on SE.

Comment: Better safe than sorry. There are always [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155720/) or [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113787/) ways to outsmart a browser.

Answer (score 12):

No.  If you actively choose to disable part of the internet, it will be disabled.  While we maintain basic functionality of the sites with or without JavaScript, we won't bend over backwards to support everything.

If you want advanced functionality on our sites, don't block it.

What's the alternative here? we *also* build a server-side render of the chart, in addition to controls for moving around and such?  Yeah...we have better things to do.

---

While we won't improve non-JS functionality here, the top bar for the noscript warning has been added to SE.com.

Comment: He just wants the ["works best with JavaScript enabled"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4yp4A.png) bar to show up like it does on the rest of the network. That's not really an unreasonable request, is it?

Comment: @Pekka - then the question is severely mis-titled.

Comment: true. Also what he says in the  body is kinda ambiguous. (table = a huge workaround; bar = easy peasy notification)

Comment: @Pekka - not really, it's still an "or", but no...*that's* not an unreasonable request, and we'll try and get it in today.

Comment: @Nick - are there actually any rational reasons for people to disable JS, other than ideological rantings about how the internets should work with just with plain html, blah blah blah?  Your attitude above is refreshing.

Comment: @AdamRackis there is the nonzero chance that JavaScript could allow a site to do bad things if not disabled, but it borders on paranoia for browsing mainstream reputable sites.

Comment: Love [the status tags](http://i.stack.imgur.com/c1gjE.png) :-)