# I busted the Stack Overflow frame-buster-buster-buster

Tags: bug, chat, security, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Should Stack Exchange be using the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103405/should-stack-exchange-be-using-the-x-frame-options-header)

Yesterday I was hanging out in the PHP chatroom feeling a little bored, and then saw the `leave` button and remembered that it didn't ask for confirmation, so I tried putting that URL (`https://chat.stackoverflow.com/chats/leave/11`) into an image `src`, as I remember was done with the logout URL a while ago by someone else.

It didn't work, as it presented an 'are you sure' page.

Then [the Twitter "Don't Click" prank](http://dsandler.org/wp/archives/2009/02/12/dontclick) came to mind.

I put the Stack Overflow 'leave all' page in an `iframe`, expecting it to display the standard `For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.` message to appear.

**Surprisingly, it didn't.**

So, I positioned the frame inside a `<div>` set to `overflow: hidden`, and made it invisible.

I put a simple WebKit notification test in as a guise, with a button underneath labeled `notify`.

Then I added the `onload` attribute to the `iframe` that would execute a JavaScript function.
The JavaScript function would detect if it had loaded for the first time or not.

If it had loaded for a second time, the script assumes that the `leave` button has been clicked, and acts as if the button behind it had been (i.e. it displays the test notification).

I tested it, and sure enough, the chat tab went to the 'all rooms' page. I had left the room.

[I then posted a message in chat to test it.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=6215374#6215374)

[Nick](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/710827/nick) was the first to [fall for it](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=6215380#6215380) (sorry Nick).

[Levi](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/538216/levi-morrison) was the [first to notice](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=6215386#6215386), [but still didn't fully realize what was happening](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=6215428#6215428).

Then [Shyam](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1172900/shyam-k) [noticed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=6215881#6215881).

I was not online by then, and no-one else took any notice of it after that.

---

This morning I improved it more, and managed to bust the [frame-buster-buster-buster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/958997/1421049).

## I had created the [frame-buster-buster-buster-buster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed#comment795428_959036)!

---

My addition was the a button that logs the user out.

### How I did it:

Normally, if you put Stack Overflow in a frame, it will be busted.

I therefore applied a [`sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) to the `iframe`.

I managed to get it to ***not bust the frames***, but is would still display the alert.

I then discovered that I could put `sandbox="allow-forms"` and it would **block scripts, but allow the submission of forms**.

---

## [The demo is here.](http://shaquin.tk/experiments/test3.html)

---

#### Links:

[Demo](http://shaquin.tk/experiments/test3.html) | [Demo (half-opacity)](http://shaquin.tk/experiments/test3.html?show) | [Mirror](http://jsfiddle.net/WYpYZ/) | [Mirror (half-opacity)](http://jsfiddle.net/WYpYZ/1/)

Comment: Re-tagging this as a bug, as I don't quite see a feature request.

Comment: @NickCraver How do we make the duplicate get more attention?

Comment: This is really *really* cool! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a simple fix: set `X-Frame-Options` to `DENY` or `SAMEORIGIN`.

---

[The `X-Frame-Options` response header | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)