# Can I embed a Stack Overflow tag page on my website?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

Is it possible for my group to embed a part of Stack Overflow onto our non-SE site so we can use it for Q&A?

We have a software library, and rather than hosting our own solution for questions, we would prefer to use Stack Overflow.

Ideally we would be able to put an `iframe` on our site containing SO's [HTML tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html).

Comment: I don't understand--do you want to embed part of the site (like answers) or just tags? And if the latter, what use will that have?

Comment: [I don't think that Jeff would like that...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)

Comment: @Chris so the answer is no?

Comment: @Purmou for example am I allowed to put this page into an iframe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html

Comment: For viewing existing questions you could embed the RSS feed methinks. It's just that proclamation as support forum is frowned on (better have a separate forum/bulletin board and make it explicit). If questions come up naturally anyway, it's okay.

Comment: @Petah Like mario said, in general support questions shouldn't be dumped onto Stack Overflow, but a library's users are of course free to ask questions about said library on Stack Overflow themselves. If you'd just like to embed individual questions on your site, however, I would recommend taking a look at [StackTack](http://stackapps.com/questions/518).

Comment: You're free to _link_ to the tag and encourage your users to ask questions on SO, however moderation remains up to us. If you do link to it, please make sure you also inform people about [asking questions](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), or your users will likely have a very bad experience. Note how [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/support/) is doing that now with Super User.

Comment: @Petah: While not directly, you might be able to utilize the RSS feeds (see my [updated answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115970/140951)).

Comment: Related: [Mini SE plugin for small products](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87627/mini-se-plugin-for-small-products). (And maybe Jeff's answer to [Can I have a link to the “ask as question” page with the tag field pre-filled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33195/can-i-have-a-link-to-the-ask-as-question-page-with-the-tag-field-pre-filled/33199#33199) helps you too?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, not directly.

Jeff has indicated that there is [frame-busting code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70655/140951), and even [initially asked the StackOverflow community to help with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed).

While not a specific indicator saying you cannot do it, it's fairly obvious that they do not want you to embed any StackExchange site wholesale in another site.

That said, for your particular scenario, you *are able* to embed those questions (or at least, elements of them) in your site, as the latest questions tagged [html](/questions/tagged/html) is offered up through RSS through the following URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=html&sort=newest

You could build a widget that utilizes this feed and embed that in your website.

However, it should be said that you'd have to attribute the content back to the StackExchange site that you wish to use this content in; I'm sure the RSS feeds fall under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) that all Stack Exchange sites fall under.